# Form displays correctly on 1 landing page but not other - what am I missing?

Tags: html, css, forms, marketo

I've embedded a form built in Marketo on two landing pages on our site. I'm using the same javascript provided by Marketo for both pages (see code below). While the form appears correctly on page 1, the field label and cell appear far to the left on page 2.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix page 2 to look lik page 1?

Page 1 code:

```
[column lg="3" ] [/column] [column lg="6" md="12" sm="12" xs="12" ]<h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong>HEADLINE HERE</strong></span></h4><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #333333;">TEXT HERE</span><br /> <br /> <script src="//app-ab05.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1035"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-ab05.marketo.com", "578-AFO-782", 1035);</script>[/column] [column lg="3" ][/column]
```

Page 2 code:

```
<p>[column lg="3"] [/column] [column lg="6" md="12" sm="12" xs="12" ]</p>
<h4 style="text-align: center;">TEXT GOES HERE</h4>
<p> </p>
<script src="//app-ab05.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1035"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-ab05.marketo.com", "578-AFO-782", 1035);</script>
[/column] [column lg="3"] [/column]</p>
```

Comment: You'd need to post a demo of an actual page. We can't do anything with that code you posted.

Comment: Here's a link to a screenshot of the form that isn't rendering correctly. Is that what you meant by a demo? http://postimg.org/image/i1l9ivdu5/

And here's a link to the other page that is rendering correctly. http://postimg.org/image/imnhxzczb/

Comment: No, that's like sending a photo of yourself to a doctor and asking why you have a tummy ache. We need an actual working demo that shows the issue in real life, so to speak. Try a site like CodePen for posting a demo, r post a full rendered code example here, or link to a page that shows the issue.

Comment: I'd post the link but I'm concerned it'd be indexed and maybe the link to our test site would be discoverable via this thread. URL includes our product name. The page is made up of a number of widgets in Wordpress so I think building a demo may be tough. Is there a way to send you a private message with our test site URL?

Answer (score 0):

Page 2 looks like it has a few extra paragraph elements that Page 1 does not have. Page 2 is also missing the span element of Page 1. I would recommend removing the paragraph elements and add the span element, and then see if Page 2 looks correct. Try this:

```
[column lg="3"] [/column] [column lg="6" md="12" sm="12" xs="12" ]
<h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong>TEXT GOES HERE</strong></span>     
</h4><br /> <br /> 
<script src="//app-ab05.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1035"></form>
<script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-ab05.marketo.com", "578-AFO-782", 1035);</script>
[/column] [column lg="3"] [/column]</p>
```